# archive command repeatly failing for one particular file

Tags: postgresql, archive, archive-log

I am seeing many pg_log files full of following errors

```
2019-07-08 00:04:06 CEST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy "pg_xlog\000000010000002100000025" "D:/Programme/OmniBack/server/db80/pg/pg_xlog_archive/000000010000002100000025"
2019-07-08 00:04:07 CEST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2019-07-08 00:04:07 CEST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy "pg_xlog\000000010000002100000025" "D:/Programme/OmniBack/server/db80/pg/pg_xlog_archive/000000010000002100000025"
2019-07-08 00:04:07 CEST WARNING:  transaction log file "000000010000002100000025" could not be archived: too many failures
2019-07-08 00:05:07 CEST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1**
```

postgres.conf having settings

```
checkpoint_segments = 256
wal_buffers = 256MB
wal_level = archive
archive_mode = on
port = 7112
work_mem = 128MB
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 32719MB
listen_addresses = '*'
logging_collector = on
log_line_prefix = '%t '
archive_command = 'copy "%p" "D:/Programme/OmniBack/server/db80/pg/pg_xlog_archive/%f"'**
```

I have checked `pg_xlog` folder for this file. This file is not present in `pg_xlog` but in `pg_xlog\archive_status` with following permissions

```
pg/pg_xlog\archive_status\000000010000002100000025.ready 

KDLF\adminkdlf:(I)(F)
VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren:(I)(F)
NT-AUTORITŽT\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
VORDEFINIERT\Benutzer:(I)(RX)
```

My disk is getting full. Please tell why this issue is coming because of this others logs are still not archived. I am not sure if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is not in `pg_xlog`, but there is a `.ready` file in `archive_status`, then **somebody must have removed that file**, which is why archival is failing.

Temporarily set `archive_command = '/bin/true'` until the view `pg_stat_archiver` indicates that PostgreSQL is happy again, then set the parameter back to its original value.

**Perform a new base backup immediately after that.**

You won't be able to recover across the point where you have no WAL archives.

Try to find out which of your administrators is stupid enough to delete files from the data directory and send him or her to a PostgreSQL course.

Comment: I think now Standby will not sync up to the point due to archive failed and /bin/true parameter change. is it right?

Comment: @AdamMulla Streaming replication is independent of WAL archiving, so I don't see how that should affect a streaming replication standby.

Comment: you are correct technical point of view. what if i want  to use that all archives to apply on standby without streaming or for point in time recovery?

Comment: Of course, if you don't use streaming, but WAL shipping via `archive_command`, the standby will be broken and has to be rebuilt.

Comment: That means, If we are using archive_command and doing scp to standby without streaming replication, and we changed archive_command = '/bin/true' meanwhile due to some issues like above , post this standby must be rebuild right? it will not sync with prod.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Thanks for you comments.. your answers are genuine and correct.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - If you would be kind enough to debate on this comment of yours: `Streaming replication is independent of WAL archiving, so I don't see how that should affect a streaming replication standby`. What do you think about this use case for streaming replication:
1. Streaming replication is set up along with `restore_command` that restores WALs from a commonly accessible WAL archive directory.
2. There is failure in execution of archive_command on the primary; and the WAL file is already recycled.
3. As a result, standby can not catch up with the primary at all.

Comment: @BinitaBharati That is not streaming replication, that is WAL shipping.